# Corona SDK. Longer button pressure -> stronger effect (e.g. higher jumps)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I can't figure out any way to implement it in Corona. Have you got any idea\suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
local timeOfPressing = 9999999;
local buttonPressed = false;
local function keyListener( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        timeOfPressing = event.time;
        buttonPressed = true;
    elseif event.phase == "ended" and buttonPressed then
        local force = event.time - timeOfPressing;
        if force > maximumForce then force = maximumForce end
        buttonPressed = false;
        myJumpFunction(force);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

define and increase your force in event.phase==began.